# HP 7 Plus with Android 4.2.2 not detected on Ubuntu 14.04.1

Tags: 14.04, android, tablet, mtp, detect

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for **: 

Disk /dev/sda: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders, total 488397168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x12bb12ba

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048     8386559     4192256   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda2   *     8386560   203698175    97655808   83  Linux
/dev/sda3       203700222   488396799   142348289    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       203700224   488396799   142348288   83  Linux

$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS \n \l
```

What do I need to do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In settings of the tablet:

"USB computer connection":
We have the choice between Media device (MTP) Or Camera (PTP).

MTP is only for Windows and Mac.
PTP is for computers that don't support MTP.

So, on Linux I cannot transfer anything else than photos that too
when PTP is enabled.